# NodeJS with HDWalletProvider

Tags: truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, truffle-migration

I want to execute signed Ethereum transactions from a NodeJS program. I am creating a web3_provider like this

```
var contract = require("truffle-contract");

var provider = new HDWalletProvider("nemonic", "https://rinkeby.infura.io/xxxxx");
// if I change the above line to: var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/xxxxx");
// Everything works fine
var web3 = new Web3(provider); 

var myContract = contract(myABI);
myContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
```

When I try to execute transactions w/ HDWalletProvider, I get the error: "Account not found". Has anyone been able to use HDWalletProvider to successfully execute signed transactions? Or am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");` is installed correctly and required. `npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider --save` will install the module.

Secondly you "nemonic" phrase is improperly formatted. A seed nemonic should look like this: `retreat attack lift winter amazing noodle interest dutch craft old solve save` and is likely the cause of you error.

Comment: I replaced my seed phrase with the word "nemonic" because I didn't want to post it publicly. And HDWalletProvider is installed correctly.

Comment: That's smart, I should have recognized that. I see the problem. You can't setProvider on a contract object. The contract is either already deployed in which case you provide an address. Or you need to deploy the contract.

Comment: Could you also check your version of web3js? Thank you

Comment: That's not a contract object, its truffle contract- https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract. I am using: "truffle-contract":"^3.0.5", "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.3", "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26",

Answer (score 0):

This is the code syntax I always use in JS for HDWallet Provider. Works fine every time.

```
provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(secret, "http://IP_address:Port"),
```

Note: I use http, not http(s)